# MATLAB Datenum does not work properly with find

Tags: matlab, date, datetime, time

I have two sets of time series data which are collected with different time intervals. One is measured every 15 minutes and the other every 1 minute.

The measured variables are oxygen concentration, oxygen saturation and time, all three of which are measured using the two different instruments which have the different time intervals (6 column arrays in total).

I have two times between which I want to find the index's of all the entries at 15 minute intervals in the time column that sit between them.

```
co=1;
for i = datenum('03/11/2014/10/00/00','dd/mm/yyyy/HH/MM/SS'):datenum('03/11/2014/00/15/00','dd/mm/yyyy/HH/MM/SS')-datenum('03/11/2014/00/00/00','dd/mm/yyyy/HH/MM/SS'):('03/11/2014/16/00/00','dd/mm/yyyy/HH/MM/SS');
    u=find(xyl_time==i);
    New_O2(co,1)=xyl_o2conc(u);
    New_O2(co,2)=xyl_o2sat(u);
    v=find(sg_time==i);
    New_O2(co,3)=sg_o2conc(v);
    New_O2(co,4)=sq_o2sat(v);
    co=co+1;
end
```

however, this does not work. I have narrowed it down and its something to do with the time interval that I'm using. I want it at every 15 minutes, but when I produce the 15 minute interval and then datestr that number, it comes up with '12:15AM'. I think this is causing the problem, but have no idea how to produce just times alone i.e I just want 00:15 not 12:15 not 00:15 AM or PM. just spacings of 15 minutes for my for loop.

Comment: I dont think its because of conversion of 15 min interval to 12:15 AM. Please show me your `xyl_time` matrix.

Comment: I found a workaround that involves the use of '[a,u]=min(abs(xyl_time-i));'

<code>
co=1;
for i = datenum('03/11/2014/10/00/00','dd/mm/yyyy/HH/MM/SS'):interval:datenum('03/11/2014/16/00/00','dd/mm/yyyy/HH/MM/SS');
    [a,u]=min(abs(xyl_time-i));
    msc_o2_03(co,1)=xyl_o2conc(u);
    msc_o2_03(co,2)=xyl_o2sat(u);
    [a,v]=min(abs(Nsg_time-i));
    msc_o2_03(co,3)=Nsg_o2conc(v);
    msc_o2_03(co,4)=Nsg_o2sat(v);
    co=co+1;
end
<code>

Comment: Turns out my xyl_time array had some values that were out by fractions of milliseconds.